# Is it possible to use the url('slider.value + .jpg')?

Tags: background-image

I have a working slider and am trying to use that value to drive the background image that displays. My images are named accordingly (0.jpg,1.jpg,2,jpg,etc.)

```
function changeBackgroundImage() {
    document.getElementById("screen").style.backgroundImage = url('slider.value + .jpg');
}
```

Comment: It should work with `url(slider.value + '.jpg');` ... only the ".jpg" must be in quotes.

Comment: function changeBackgroundImage() {
    document.getElementById("screen").style.backgroundImage = url('images/'+slider.value +'.jpg');
    changeBackgroundImage();
}

Comment: That is how the whole code looks I included the 'images' at the beginning as I thought I would need too, it doesn't display when I change the slider though?

Comment: Well, does changing your slider call `changeBackgroundImage()`? Why is there a recursive call to `changeBackgroundImage();` inside your function? If anything, this will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: function changeBackgroundImage() {
    document.getElementById("screen").style.backgroundImage = url('images/'+slider.value+'.jpg');
}

Comment: slider.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
 date = Math.round(slider.value);
 updateDisplay();
 changeBackgroundImage();
 console.log(slider.value)
})

I have it like this but then when I change the slider I get an "VM3426 script.js:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at changeBackgroundImage (VM3426 script.js:35)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (VM3426 script.js:63)"

Comment: Also thanks a bunch for helping.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to change or add details - makes code easier to read than in the (unformatted) comments.